# When you should use Room Caching vs Retrofit Caching?

Tags: android, sqlite, caching, retrofit2, okhttp

When you should use Room Caching vs Retrofit Caching, considering the data I am caching is not a relation data?

Where cached data are stored and cleared, what is the default size of it and what happens when LRU kicks in. Is it the same behavior for both room and retrofit.

My few api's are returning 304 based on **if-modified-header**, and i was storing the data in room to get the cached result, but now i think i can avoid db and make use of retrofit caching.

Wanted to understand if retrofit behavior is same as room's caching behavior if my data is not a relational data.

Thanks in advance.